# Make that request shorter?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I just wanted to know if it was possible to make that request more shorter because I want to create a View with that request

```
SELECT distinct joueurs.nom, joueurs.prenom, joueurs.numero,joueurs.moyenne, equipes.nom
FROM joueurs
JOIN equipes ON equipes.equipeId = joueurs.equipeId
WHERE joueurs.equipeid = 1 
ORDER BY joueurs.moyenne DESC
LIMIT 3;

SELECT distinct joueurs.nom, joueurs.prenom, joueurs.numero,joueurs.moyenne, equipes.nom
FROM joueurs
JOIN equipes ON equipes.equipeId = joueurs.equipeId
WHERE joueurs.equipeid = 2
ORDER BY joueurs.moyenne DESC
LIMIT 3;

SELECT distinct joueurs.nom, joueurs.prenom, joueurs.numero,joueurs.moyenne, equipes.nom
FROM joueurs
JOIN equipes ON equipes.equipeId = joueurs.equipeId
WHERE joueurs.equipeid = 3
ORDER BY joueurs.moyenne DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Without using ("UNION") **

Comment: which version of `mysql` are you using?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8.0, you can use the window function `row_number`

```
SELECT 
    distinct joueurs.nom, 
    joueurs.prenom, 
    joueurs.numero,
    joueurs.moyenne, 
    equipes.nom
from
(
  SELECT 
    distinct joueurs.nom, 
    joueurs.prenom, 
    joueurs.numero,
    joueurs.moyenne, 
    equipes.nom,
    row_number() over (partition by joueurs.equipeid order by joueurs.moyenne DESC) as rnk
  FROM joueurs
  JOIN equipes 
  ON equipes.equipeId = joueurs.equipeId
  WHERE joueurs.equipeid IN (1, 2, 3)
) val
where rnk <= 3
```